# F# FAKE - Unable to get FAKE to merge placeholder arguments in .nuspec file

Tags: f#, nuget, nuget-package, f#-fake

I have the following FAKE file with this code for packaging together NuGet packages in a solution: https://github.com/Aaronontheweb/akka-monitoring/blob/master/build.fsx#L143

```
for nuspec in !! "src/**/*.nuspec" do
        printfn "Creating nuget packages for %s" nuspec

        CleanDir workingDir

        let project = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension nuspec 
        let projectDir = Path.GetDirectoryName nuspec
        let projectFile = (!! (projectDir @@ project + ".*sproj")) |> Seq.head
        let releaseDir = projectDir @@ @"bin\Release"
        let packages = projectDir @@ "packages.config"        
        let packageDependencies = if (fileExists packages) then (getDependencies packages) else []
        let dependencies = packageDependencies @ getAkkaDependency project
        let releaseVersion = release.NugetVersion
        let desc = description project

        let pack outputDir  =
            NuGetHelper.NuGet
                (fun p ->
                    { p with
                        Description = desc
                        Authors = authors
                        Copyright = copyright
                        Project =  project
                        Properties = ["Configuration", "Release"]
                        ReleaseNotes = release.Notes |> String.concat "\n"
                        Version = releaseVersion
                        Tags = tags |> String.concat " "
                        OutputPath = outputDir
                        WorkingDir = workingDir
                        Dependencies = dependencies })
                nuspec

        // Copy dll, pdb and xml to libdir = workingDir/lib/net45/
        ensureDirectory libDir
        !! (releaseDir @@ project + ".dll")
        ++ (releaseDir @@ project + ".pdb")
        ++ (releaseDir @@ project + ".xml")
        ++ (releaseDir @@ project + ".ExternalAnnotations.xml")
        |> CopyFiles libDir

        // Copy all src-files (.cs and .fs files) to workingDir/src
        let nugetSrcDir = workingDir @@ @"src/"
        // CreateDir nugetSrcDir

        let isCs = hasExt ".cs"
        let isFs = hasExt ".fs"
        let isAssemblyInfo f = (filename f).Contains("AssemblyInfo")
        let isSrc f = (isCs f || isFs f) && not (isAssemblyInfo f) 
        CopyDir nugetSrcDir projectDir isSrc

        //Remove workingDir/src/obj and workingDir/src/bin
        removeDir (nugetSrcDir @@ "obj")
        removeDir (nugetSrcDir @@ "bin")

        // Create both normal nuget package and symbols nuget package. 
        // Uses the files we copied to workingDir and outputs to nugetdir
        printfn "nugetDir %s" nugetDir
        pack nugetDir
```

And the following .nuspec file https://github.com/Aaronontheweb/akka-monitoring/blob/master/src/Akka.Monitoring/Akka.Monitoring.Nuspec

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <metadata xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <id>@project@</id>
    <title>@project@@title@</title>
    <version>@build.number@</version>
    <authors>@authors@</authors>
    <owners>@authors@</owners>
    <licenseUrl>https://github.com/Aaronontheweb/akka-monitoring/blob/master/LICENSE</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>https://github.com/Aaronontheweb/akka-monitoring</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>https://raw.githubusercontent.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/gh-pages/images/icon-32x32.png</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>@description@</description>
    <releaseNotes>@releaseNotes@</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>@copyright@</copyright>
    <tags>@tags@</tags>
    @dependencies@
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Since upgrading to the latest version of FAKE and NuGet, I get the following error:

```
Time Elapsed 00:00:01.03
Finished Target: Build
Starting Target: CopyOutput (==> Build)
Creating D:\Repositories\olympus\akkadotnet-performance-counters\bin\Akka.Monitoring
Creating D:\Repositories\olympus\akkadotnet-performance-counters\bin\Akka.Monitoring.StatsD
Finished Target: CopyOutput
Starting Target: CleanNuget
Creating D:\Repositories\olympus\akkadotnet-performance-counters\bin\nuget
Finished Target: CleanNuget
Starting Target: BuildRelease (==> CopyOutput, CleanNuget)
Finished Target: BuildRelease
Starting Target: Nuget (==> BuildRelease)
Creating nuget packages for D:\Repositories\olympus\akkadotnet-performance-counters\src\Akka.Monitoring\Akka.Monitoring.
Nuspec
Creating D:\Repositories\olympus\akkadotnet-performance-counters\bin\build
Creating D:\Repositories\olympus\akkadotnet-performance-counters\bin\build\src\
Deleting D:\Repositories\olympus\akkadotnet-performance-counters\bin\build\src\obj
D:\Repositories\olympus\akkadotnet-performance-counters\bin\build\src\bin does not exist.
nugetDir bin\nuget
D:\Repositories\olympus\akkadotnet-performance-counters\.nuget\nuget.exe pack -Symbols -Version 0.3.3 -OutputDirectory "
D:\Repositories\olympus\akkadotnet-performance-counters\bin\nuget" "D:\Repositories\olympus\akkadotnet-performance-count
ers\src\Akka.Monitoring\Akka.Monitoring.Nuspec"    -Properties Configuration="Release"
Running build failed.
Error:
System.Exception: Error during NuGet package creation. D:\Repositories\olympus\akkadotnet-performance-counters\.nuget\nu
get.exe pack -Symbols -Version 0.3.3 -OutputDirectory "D:\Repositories\olympus\akkadotnet-performance-counters\bin\nuget
" "D:\Repositories\olympus\akkadotnet-performance-counters\src\Akka.Monitoring\Akka.Monitoring.Nuspec"    -Properties Co
nfiguration="Release"
The element 'metadata' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd' cannot contain text. Lis
t of possible elements expected: 'references, summary, frameworkAssemblies, developmentDependency, language, dependencie
s' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd'.
   at Fake.NuGetHelper.NuGet(FSharpFunc`2 setParams, String nuspecOrProjectFile) in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\NuGet\N
ugetHelper.fs:line 406
   at FSI_0001.Build.createNugetPackages[a](a _arg1) in D:\Repositories\olympus\akkadotnet-performance-counters\build.fs
x:line 185
   at FSI_0001.Build.clo@228-8.Invoke(Unit _arg1) in D:\Repositories\olympus\akkadotnet-performance-counters\build.fsx:l
ine 229
   at Fake.TargetHelper.runSingleTarget(TargetTemplate`1 target) in C:\code\fake\src\app\FakeLib\TargetHelper.fs:line 41
1
```

The TL;DR; of it appears to be that FAKE isn't actually making its placeholder substitutions on the .nuspec file anymore and NuGet is getting the literal content of the file, instead of the merged file with the supplied programmatic values.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: wow. that sounds like a regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FAKE was looking for ".nuspec" files but your file was named ".Nuspec". https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/commit/15dc617624ac514268b8e9a4bd80dd1203e61054 should fix it. Release in process.

Next time you might want to open a FAKE issue. Then I'm fixing it faster.